# How can I make EditText control take more free space?

Tags: android

In the following UI, I hope the two buttons both btnAddress and btnDelete take minimum space, 
and editnumber take max space, how can I do? Need I use RelativeLayout layout? Thanks!

BTW, the following code, the btnDelete button only display a part.

[image]

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editnumber"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
            android:phoneNumber="true"
            android:ems="10" >
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAddress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"           
            android:text="@string/BtnAddressMin" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
            android:text="@string/BtnDeleteMin" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it. Giving editnumber a weight of 1. Leve the rest as it is.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editnumber"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_weight="1"                  
        android:phoneNumber="true"
        android:ems="10" >
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAddress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/BtnAddressMin" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/BtnDeleteMin" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the `android:layout_weight="1` to edit text .No need to change it to relative layout

```
       <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editnumber"
        android:layout_width="0dp"//no need to specifing the width if parent layout is horizontal
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
        android:phoneNumber="true"
        android:layout_weight="1";>
    </EditText>
```

Doing this `Edittext` will take maximum space and remaing space will be left for other `View`.Other then this no need to change anything in your  xml

Answer (score 1):

Instead of fixing the length of `EditText` with `ems`, use `layout_weight` to fill the remaining space.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editnumber"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    android:layout_weight="1"         
    android:phoneNumber="true" />
```

Edit: I'm not sure if `android:phoneNumber="true"` is still recommended or not, but I would change it to `android:inputType="phone"` instead.